# What is the compression work?

Tags: thermodynamics

A cylinder contains 2 kg of steam at 200 kPa and 200 $^\circ$C. Now steam is compressed at constant pressure until its temperature rises to 250 $^\circ$C. What is the work done during this compression process?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. This appears to be a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) question. Unless you show some work, thoughts, or effort, it is likely to get put on hold.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate work at constant pressure, you need the following:

$$w=-P \Delta V$$

where $w$ is work, $P$ is pressure and $\Delta V$ is the change in volume.

You will need to solve some gas laws relations to get both $P$ and $\Delta V$ in terms of the single variable $T$.

Algebraically, it will simplify to $P\Delta V = nR\Delta T$, assuming ideality.

If you need to assume a non-ideal gas (which is a good assumption for water at high pressure). If we use the van der Waals equation, things get dicey and calculus is needed. I'm hoping you don't need calculus:

$$d[(P-\frac{n^2a}{V^2})(V-nb)]=d(nRT)$$

$$d(PV-\frac{n^2a}{V}-nbP+\frac{n^3ab}{V^2})=d(nRT)$$

$$PdV+VdP+\frac{n^2a}{V^2}dV-nbdP-\frac{2n^3ab}{V^3}dV=nRdT+RTdn$$

Since $n$ and $P$ are constant $dP=0$ and $dn=0$

$$PdV+\frac{n^2a}{V^2}dV-\frac{2n^3ab}{V^3}dV=nRdT$$

$$\int_{V_i}^{V_f}(P+\frac{n^2a}{V^2}-\frac{2n^3ab}{V^3})dV=\int_{T_i}^{T_f}nRdT$$